# IE8 bug : script innerhtml load

Tags: youtube-api, innerhtml, swfobject

I've worked on a loader for Youtube video using swfobject.
Plugin used : jQuery 1.6.4 + SWFobject 2.2

Everything works great execpts on IE8 ! it crash at script.innerHTML...

```
<div id"youtube"><div id="player"></div></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

SCRIPT

```
function loadYoutube(videoID)
{
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementById("youtube").appendChild(script);
script.innerHTML = 'var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "transparent", allowfullscreen:"true" }; var atts = { id: "player" }; swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoID+'?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3", "player", "870", "550", "8", "flash/expressInstall.swf", null, params, atts);';
}
loadYoutube('BoEKWtgJQAU')​​​;​
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IE8 (and IE7 I believe) has a problem with innerHTML and will crash if you try and use it in this manner. I had a similar problem and solved it by using .text instead of .innerHTML.

Because this is only an IE8/IE7 issue, you should put in some logic to test for IE8/IE7 and use .text instead of .innerHTML. I was using jQuery so was able to test for IE8 like this:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 8) {
    script.text = 'var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "transparent", allowfullscreen:"true" }; var atts = { id: "player" }; swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoID+'?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3", "player", "870", "550", "8", "flash/expressInstall.swf", null, params, atts);';
} else {
    script.innerHTML = 'var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "transparent", allowfullscreen:"true" }; var atts = { id: "player" }; swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoID+'?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3", "player", "870", "550", "8", "flash/expressInstall.swf", null, params, atts);';
}
```

If you are not using jQuery, there are many examples out there that show you how to test for different browser versions.